# Elementary OS on USB installs GRUB on the laptop instead of the USB

Tags: boot, grub2

Trying to install Elementary OS to a USB stick , ran into a few problems:

I booted from another live usb, formatted a 28GB ext4 for Linux (`/dev/sdb1`) and a ESP (`/dev/sdb5`) on the USB, chose to install bootloader on `/dev/sdb`. The installer did its things and after it was done I realized that the ESP I created was empty and that GRUB has been installed in (`/dev/sda`). Now the USB sticks, as expected, only boots on his laptop.

How can I reinstall GRUB on the USB stick?

Comment: It works  if you disable or disconnect the internal drive before you start the installation. See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312)

Comment: Got it, shouldn't have used a laptop

Comment: In some laptops it is rather easy to unplug the internal drive. It is more difficult in other laptops. But there are [alternatives](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510773/two-grub-installations-destroying-each-other/510916#510916).